# How to print data without popup window it should directly go to print on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Following is my code for print.

```
function printDiv() {
     window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById("printableTable").innerHTML;
     window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
     window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();
}
```

Comment: i am using angular 4

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printDiv() 
{

  var divToPrint=document.getElementById('DivIdToPrint');

  var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');

  newWin.document.open();

  newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+printableTable.innerHTML+'</body></html>');

  newWin.document.close();

  setTimeout(function(){newWin.close();},10);

}
</script>
```